# Django admin upload files inline without Model

Tags: python, django

I have model with `JSONField` that holds uploaded file (there is no FileField in the model).

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ....
    attachments = fields.JSONField(null=True)
    ....
```

Example of JSON

> [
>   {"id": "file_id",
>    "url": "file_url_at_S3",
>   "type": "MIME type"
>   }
>   ]

I want to build an admin interface so a user can fill `Task` details AND upload files that will be uploaded to S3 and resulted json will be saved in the database. So I decided to use custom `Form` class to handle it.

My `AdminModel` is

```
@admin.register(Task)
class TaskAdmin(MarkdownxModelAdmin):
    form = TaskForm
    exclude = ('created_at', 'updated_at', 'attachments')
    list_display = ('message', 'publish_at')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        upload_result = upload_files_to_s3(form.cleaned_data.get('attachments', []),
                                           task_id=obj.id)
        obj.attachments = upload_result
        super(TaskAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Where `MarkdownxModelAdmin` is just a subclass of `ModelAdmin` for markdown.

My custom form is

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    attachments = MultiFileField() # redefine field from the model
    ....

    def clean(self):
         # validations...

    class Meta:
        model = Task            
        fields = '__all__'
```

All admin interface is
[image]

I'd like inline style of `attachments` like from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin). So a user can add files one-by-one with a small preview or with the uploaded file path. So the interface looks like this [image]

What's the best solution here?